# Drupal and css related questions

Tags: discussion

I have several CSS questions related to AT adaptive themes and how to improve this for a few sites. If I asked this question here I get feedback that they are not belonging here as it is not programming related. For me this reaction is very doubtfull and having a discussion about this does not solve the problem.

If I post these CSS questions in other forums (outside stockexchange) the first reaction I get back is: wauw whay a lot of css styles. Could you not simplify this? Or . you should post this question in drupal category. Answers Which are very logical if you don not understand the working of drupal architecture.

So how to deal with kinds of questions without getting voted down here. 
- Is there are a anothere place where this should go?
- Should people voted the question up? 
- Should I asked a moderater if the question is voted down?

Answer (score 3):

Once the CSS has been prepared and sent to the client, there's nothing left for Drupal to get involved with, that's why such questions are off topic here.

CSS is a universal Language (sort of) and what applies to the markup produced by a Drupal site applies equally to the markup produced by any other method. There's nothing Drupal-specific about questions like these:

- How do I make *x* look like *y* with CSS?
- How do I find which CSS class or ID to target?

Those, and similar CSS-related questions, can be solved by learning the language and how to use browser dev tools to your advantage. Obviously those are not Drupal disciplines so covering them here would be going against the purpose of the site.

Stack Overflow is the right place to ask CSS questions, but you must remember that Stack Exchange sites are designed to be repositories of knowledge, not personal support forums. You mention that you've been asked *Could you not simplify this?*, and that's kind of the point....

An SE site is not somewhere you can post a link to your site, or an entire web page of styles let's say, and expect someone to dig through them all to find out what your issue is. It's too broad, there's too much room for ambiguity, and it simply doesn't make a good question for a Q+A site.

What you need to do is break the problem down into its smallest parts, and produce a small, self-contained example that demonstrates the issue. Don't get me wrong, this is a skill in and of itself, and one that takes a while to learn, but it's necessary to ask good programming questions (and those in closely related genres).

I'll try to address your individual questions as well:

> So how to deal with kinds of questions without getting voted down here

Ask well researched, clear, on-topic questions in such a way that can be useful to future visitors of the site. This excludes questions about CSS/HTML syntax or general CSS/HTML development as already mentioned.

> Is there are a anothere place where this should go?

As already mentioned the right place in the SE network is Stack Overflow. Beyond that I don't know where you'd ask about CSS, I tend not to stray too far from these walls for such help.

> Should people voted the question up?

Not really possible to answer that, but if you want to look at it logically, then questions about CSS, which are off topic, should probably not be voted up, no.

> Should I asked a moderator if the question is voted down?

Moderators have no say in how people use their votes so please don't raise flags for us to look into them, unless you suspect that one or more users are consistently targeting you with downvotes in a malicious manner.

Above all, read through the literature in the [Help Center](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help), that will give you a fuller idea of what this site is about, and the best way to use it. And, of course, raise individual concerns like this on the meta site, not on the main site itself.

Comment: One little thing to add: Of course upvoting offtopic questions makes no sense, but if, apart from being offtopic, they are not that bad, they shouldn't be downvoted either. On the other hand, dumping whole CSS files kinda *is* bad :(

Comment: Hi Molot, thxs for the answer. It is not me questioning "Could you not simplify this?" it is the answer of questions a post.

Comment: That's right @Justme, when others ask you "could you not simplify this?" it means they're not prepared to spend the amount of time it would take to fully digest and understand all the code you're showing them. These people are volunteers, they don't have the time or motivation to learn every intricacy of your site to help identify one small CSS problem. The idea is that _you_ need to present your question is such a way that makes it easy for them to answer. For that you need a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: So in basic you say this is not the correct group as it is not drupal related and you say that stack overflow is the place for this. So in which community should it be posted then?

Comment: That's correct. If you feel that your question is of sufficient quality and detail for Stack Overflow, after reading their help center/about/etc to make sure, then that's the correct place to post it. It's not for me to tell you where you should post questions, I can just tell you what is and isn't on-topic on Drupal Answers, and point you in the direction of the literature of other sites to decide for yourself if your question would be suitable there.

Comment: Oke thanxs for your help. I understand this is not the place and where it is a good place on stack overflow is not know. There is no specifiek css comunnity for that.

Comment: Not on Stack Exchange I don't think, no. SO is about the closest to a CSS community you'd get because it's very nearly programming (and there are thousands of existing CSS questions there so we know they're acceptable).\

Comment: @Justme there are also [CSS questions on Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/css), so at least some of them are acceptable there. As usual, read their help center firs.

Answer (score 2):

As someone who downvoted and voted to close some of your questions I want to tell that [Clive's answer](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3276/16495) nails it. We can't know all themes and their class / css structure. And after simplifying your problems, it's no longer Drupal in any way. It is, I'm afraid, a common misconception - not all things you see during Drupal development truly is Drupal related. As far as i remember there was similar issue with [Programmers Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) - scope of this site [changed over time](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5654/171557), because less restrictive rules caused experts to go away. Hell, as far as I remember (sorry for lack of reference) someone even argued that making sandwiches is on-topic if they are meant to be eaten during coding. I know, I know, it is extreme case, but that's where "I see it with X so it is X question" can lead you. There is a long way from CSS to sandwiches, but I don't think we want to make even one step in that direction.

My votes to close were not meant as punishment. My downvotes kinda were - for apparent lack of own effort in making questions easier to answer, or lack of information about things already tried. But it was never personal. I don't say there was no effort on your part, only that particular question lacks that information.

Comment: Exactly: It's not that every problem I could find creating a Drupal site makes a question on Drupal Answers. I know that users could not know whenever a problem is caused by Drupal, but there is a topic for good reasons. Users should just not take a closure as something personal: Closing a question is not a punishment.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I have some closed questions, too. I don't mind. Especially duplicates - I really like how it can either show me already posted solution or explain by example where my question was unclear (if I believe it's not a dup but I failed to make differences clear to readers).